# How to shift a matrix by x rows and y columns in the most efficient way?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays, matrix

My objective is to shift rows by x and columns by y in a 2d matrix. My problem is to solve this objective in an efficient manner.

x and y could be negative or positive. Negative would mean up/left and positive would mean down/right.

My current solution is something like this:

```
def rotate_columns(col, y):
    new_col_position = col+y if y < 0 else (col+n-y)
    return new_col_position
def rotate_rows(row, x):
    new_row_position = row+x if x < 0 else (row+m-x)
    return new_row_position

def shift(x,y):
    N = M.copy()
    for col in range(n):
new_col_position = rotate_columns(col)
        for row in range(m):
            N[row][new_col_position] = M[row][col]
    for row in range(m):
        new_row_position = rotate_rows(row)
        for col in range(n):
            N[new_row_position][col] = M[row][col]
```

An example:
Say, a given matrix is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

with x = 2, y = 1, it would be:

```
6 4 5
9 7 8
3 1 2
```

Is there a better way to solve this? By better, I mean better time complexity.

Comment: Your algorithm already seems to run in linear time. You might be able to save some constant factors, but that depends on the exact computation model (how matrices are implemented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could think of a time-efficient solution which is not good in terms of memory.

We will carry out duplication of the given array.

For eg.

Initial Array:

[image]

We can have 4 duplicate copies of the same array, each attached to form a huge square.

Big Array looks like:

[image]

Within this Big Array, let me call my result as the Result Array.

Initially, when we have no rotation involved, the result array looks like:

[image]

The Blue colored box represents the result array.

The top_left_index of the result array = (0, 0). [Image above]

After that, suppose we rotate 1 row, the blue colored box shifts down as follows:

[image]

The top_left_index of the result array = (**1**, 0). [Image above]

After that, suppose we rotate 1 column, the blue colored box shifts right as follows:

[image]

The top_left_index of the result array becomes = (**1**, **1**). [Image above]

After that, suppose we rotate 1 row, the blue colored box shifts down as follows:

[image]

The top_left_index of the result array becomes = (**2**, **1**). [Image above]

After that, suppose we rotate 2 cols, the blue colored box shifts right as follows:

[image]

The top_left_index of the result array becomes = (**2**, **3**). [Image above]

This is how the entire logic works.

We just need to store the top left index of the blue box. Whenever asked for the result, we can display the elements of the blue-colored box.

So, the entire problem boils down to calculating the top left index of the blue box.

**Time Complexity of changing the index**: O(1)

**Space complexity**: O(n^2)

However, there exist corner cases that need to be handled. Once such corner case is as below:

[image]

Handling this corner case is not difficult. In case we feel that the resultant array's bounds are overflowing the boundary of the Big array, we need to reduce the value of our top_left_index such that the entire square fits in the array. 
For eg.,

In the above image, the top_left_index (2,4) overflows the bounds of Big Array.

We simply reduce the overflowing index by the respective dimension of our original array and make it:

(2, 4 - 3 ) = (2, 1).

Now, things look beautiful again.

Comment: This is very similar to what the OP is already doing, only your method requires more memory.

Comment: Agreed. 

However, at every shift, what OP does is:
1. Make an entire copy of the original array. (Consider it to O(1))
2. Copy the values from the old array to new. (O(n^2))

The suggested solution does the following at every shift:
1. Gets an appropriate value of the top_left_index in O(1). 

So, in case we have an operation in which there are a lot of shifts, the provided solution seems to work better. 

Correct me if I am getting it wrong. 

Thanks :)